# Adding a route with time-limited validity?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iproute

I have read different routing protocols, each one adds routes with limited time validity to routing table. Is there a method in Linux/Ubuntu, without installing any routing daemon, to add a time limited route? If so how?

NOTE: I was looking at man pages of `ip route add ...` and **rto_min** looks important for that, but I don't fully understand its function.

Comment: Uh? `rto_min` has absolutely nothing to do with how long the route remains valid. It's about a Retransmission TimeOut. The way to create a time-limited route is to remove it after the desired time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rto_min` has absolutely nothing to do with how long the route remains valid. It's about a Retransmission TimeOut.

The way to create a time-limited route is to remove it after the desired time. That's the way routing demons do it. You can do it manually with an [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) job.